# el timer c# dice que no se puede convertir cs0023, cs0019, y cs0019

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Mi evento:

```
        private void StartApplication_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (StartApplication < 10)
            {
                StartApplication++;
            }
            if (StartApplication == 10)
            {
                this.Hide();
                new inicio().Show();
            }
        }
```

**ERRORES**

CS0023
El operador '++' no se puede aplicar al operando del tipo 'Timer'

CS0019
El operador '<' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo 'Timer' y 'int'

CS0019
El operador '==' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo 'Timer' y 'int'

Comment: Hola, me puedes decir si entendiste la respuesta dada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu **variable StartApplication** no es un **integer**, es un objeto de tipo **Timer**, no tienen nada que ver el uno con el otro, para resolver tu problema debes declarar una **variable global** que te servirá como si fuera un cronometro. Esta variable se declara afuera de tu método, a nivel de clase.

```
int cronometro = 0;
```

Aquí se declara la **variable global cronometro** de tipo **int** afuera del método, esta variable es la que servirá de contador de tiempo para resolver el problema planteado.

Entonces tu código quedaría así:

```
private void StartApplication_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (cronometro < 10)
   {
      cronometro++;
   }
   else if (cronometro >= 10)
   {
      cronometro = 0;
      StartApplication.Enabled = false;
      this.Hide();
      new inicio().Show();
   }
}
```

Aquí cambio ciertas condiciones, por ejemplo pongo un **else if** y la **condición cronometro == 10**, la sustituyo por la **condición cronometro >= 10**, para evitar cualquier posible problema, y cuando se entre al **else if**, reinicio el valor de la **variable global cronometro** a 0, por si debes usar esa variable de nuevo y para que el **timer** no continúe ejecutándose lo desactivo poniendo su **propiedad Enabled** a **false**.